# react-native Router flux

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-native-router-flux

```
for index.android.js

 1. import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
```

than

[image]

I get an error adding, Can there be help ?
Thank you

Comment: Why you can't try the [@react-community/react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) library? This is the official library, recommended by Facebook to use with React Native.

Comment: Thank you, I will try today :)

Comment: @godkorder If you remove this line, and any line references to this, it works? The error message seems unrelated to this to me.

Comment: @geckob 
if I remove the line, it works

Comment: Try to reset the cache. `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Comment: it did not work @geckob
Project link --> https://www.dropbox.com/s/wz9v59d9379fuzp/react-native-sidemenu-master.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

I've been facing this same issue before. Just changed the version of react-native-router-flux on my packege.json to 3.40.1 and everything works fine.

Hope this help :)